# Image Crash on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pictures

Some Image/Pictures crashes on Chrome and some appears,even if after refreshing the page Pics do not appear.I have faced these problem with several install-able and portable version of chrome on Windows 7,Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: And they opened on other browsers as they should have too?

Comment: No,on other browsers it doesn't occur.

Comment: I mean to say they opened properly on other browser?